# Programming the "phone" app in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, phone-call

In iPhones, is it possible to code the "phone" app. What I want to do is play a sound when the person on the other line hangs up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I had a dime for every time I've had an entrepreneur ask me if it's possible to do "video ringers" (video replacing an audio-only ringtone) or "record a conversation straight from the phone app", I'd probably have a couple dollars.

In any event, Apple does not allow developers to modify anything to do with the Phone functionality, as it's considered a security and privacy risk.

Answer (score 0):

The Security of apple will not allow you to perform this because its against the security & privacy of apple.